# UITableViewCell ID

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uitableview

I just started programming in Swift for iOS and I want to make an app with a table view and a search bar. When you click on a cell there will be played a sound. But when I search, I can't simply use `indexPath.row` because another song wil be played.

Is it possible to give every `UITableViewCell` an identifier so I can call a sound by the identifier of the tapped cell?

Comment: you can set `cell.tag`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore It does not solve the problem, but you answered the question though

Comment: @LucasHuang it's not an answer but a comment or an idea :)

Answer (score 2):

When you search, you should ideally have another array storing the search results.

Lets say you have 10 cells.

You will have an array of 10 sounds which you will play based on indexPath.row

And you will also have another searchResultsArray which you are using to display the search results.

So, whenever didSelectRow is called, use the new array, and play sound from that array.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to achieve this is changing the `dataSource` of your tableView and call its `reloadData` when showing search results.

Then, you could always know playing which song in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` according to `indexPath.row` (because the `dataSource` of the tableView is up to date).

Besides, you'd better not use `cell.tag` because of the cell's reusing strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand how `indexPath.row` in **UITableView** and **UISearchBar** work before doing anything like that. Normally, the `indexPath.row` is used as an identifier. And as long as you go further, you will find it extremely useful.

And I think you have misunderstanding because when you click on that, you should be able to play the sound. That's why we need the data source when we set up the **UITableView**. That's what we call parallel data structures. It means that the UITableViewCell's index matches with the index from your data source.

After searching, you will have another data source. So, please be careful on that. Because you are not manipulating the original data source any more.